# If I wanted to take a cat over an ocean, would it teleport behind my boat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found this on the [Minecraft Wiki page for Ocelots](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot):

> A cat will not teleport: [...]
>
> - If none of the blocks on the edge of a 5×5×1 region centered on the player are transparent blocks with an opaque block below and another transparent block above.

Does this mean that if I tame a cat (which is *not* sitting), and boat across an ocean, the cat will be on the beach and not teleport near the water? If cats swim, will they drown after a while in the water, even if I use a lead?

Comment: If your cat is initially located inside spawn chunk, which is always loaded, you can just go wherever you want and cat will be there.(And try not to get too close to the land in the middle of a trip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pets can only teleport to land, so if you cross a large enough body of water and they can't keep up by swimming, they will be unloaded and will be unable to teleport to you when you come to land.

One way around this is to swim or boat slowly so that they keep up. Another way is to make a path through the nether and take them through that way.

Comment: Make shure they are still in render distance though. stob by an islande every 100 blocks (or build one) so your pets (wolves as well) will teleport there and they will stay in render dictance

Comment: @codermaster That's good idea! If you bring some lily pads and blocks, you can do that even if there's no island nearby path.

Comment: thats true but so many lillypads are hard to come by, you will need 5×5=25 lillypads at least per 100 blocks and I am not shure if they teleport to the pads as well.

Comment: @codermaster you only need 1 lily pad because you can place blocks under the lily pad (and it automatically breaks).

Comment: yeah that will work but i thought you wanted to make it out of lillypads

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, and no the pet does not teleport behind your boat.
but he does swim behind you if you use a lead. (only if the bottom of the ocean is not deep. that's about 2 blocks high. Otherwise, your pet will drown.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a lead (requires some string and one slimeball) to pull animals behind the boat. You can pull more than one at the same time.